# OpenGL benchmark for Linux?

Tags: linux, opengl

I'm looking for an OpenGL benchmark tool for Linux. Something sort of similar to 3DMark on Windows. Is there anything at all? I tried Phoronix, was not impressed (nothing seemed to run at all).

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try [this](http://www.unigine.com/products/tropics/) benchmark. There are a few more on the site if this is not what you are looking for (downloadable by mirror torrent interestingly enough).